# C++: Client-Server Distributed Processing Idea, close connection after data is sent, re open when task is finished?

Tags: c++, network-programming, client-server, cloud, distributed-computing

So, I'm trying to think of the best way to have a distributed computing client-server architecture that allows for the most possible clients without being too hard on the server.

*Note, I'm using the boost library, though I haven't started any client / server code yet.

I *think* I want to open a TCP connection from a client to the server, saying "hey I'll do some work for ya", they server sends a task and data for that task during that connection, then closes that connection so that the server doesn't have a ton of open socket threads.  When the client finishes processing, it would re-connect to the server and send the completed data (closing the connection again if there are no further tasks to be done).

Is this a good idea? What is the best way to go about doing this?

It's possible that the server would need to manage up to 256 clients (biggest case).

Comment: 256 clients isn't really that many... I get the impression from your description you're planning on having 1 thread per client connection.  Is that right?

Comment: Well, thats what I'm trying to avoid. Because having that many simultaneous threads could become intensive on a small machine? idk. I'm not really sure if 256 threads is a lot or not... but I feel like > 10 threads is a lot.  Just trying to be optimal.

Comment: I've usually used some pool of worker threads for processing connections, read/writing to them as data became available and using 'select' (not sure what the boost equivalent is) for checking when the sockets are ready to do some work

Answer (score 2):

Have you looked at Amazon's MapReduce service?  It is built for exactly this sort of thing.

http://aws.amazon.com/elasticmapreduce/

It is massively scalable, and will handle just about any job you can throw at it.

EDIT: If you want an open solution, I suggest looking at Apache Hadoop and its MapReduce offering.  Also, you  can check out OpenStack to host your own cloud infrastructure, if that seems advantageous for your application.

http://www.openstack.org/

Comment: Thats neat. Costs money though. The project I'm working on isn't funded, so this isn't really an option.  For right now, we have like.. 4 computers to work with. If the project gets big enough though, this could certainly be an option. What I might do is something similar to Folding@home, where people just install a thing, and it runs when the system is idle.

Comment: FYI - Added more info on free alternatives.

Comment: I like the openstack solution, +1

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest as an option to explore the [BOINC software](http://boinc.berkeley.edu/trac/wiki/SoftwareDevelopment) which is open-source and is precisely designed with this in mind. This assumes that the task will not need to communicate to other clients, just with the server

This is the software used by seti@home, einstein@home, folding@home and almost anything @home!